# Updating Records in Rails with bulk_insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a Model with 3 params `:season`, `:player` `:total_pts`

When I call `Model.create(seaon: 2018, player: 123, total_pts: 100)` I want any record where `season` and `player` already exist to be 'overwritten'; or if it doesn't exist create a new one

I'm using the `bulk_insert` gem which might complicate things

What's the best way to handle this in rails? In searching around I found `find_or_create_by` and putting `before_create` in the model.

My code looks something like this

```
array_of_full_hashes = [{seaon: 2018, player: 123, total_pts: 100}, {seaon: 2018, player: 444, total_pts: 25}]
Model.bulk_insert do |worker|
 array_of_full_hashes.each do |attrs|
  worker.add(attrs)
 end
end
```

Comment: If you're using MySQL, you can pass `update_duplicates: true` to bulk_insert as a parameter. source: https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert#update-duplicates-mysql

Comment: Using postgres unfortunately.. Right now the simplest method seems to be just deleting the old records and then creating the new ones..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the bulk_insert gem's PostgreSQL adapter code [takes no action when there's a conflict](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert/blob/master/lib/bulk_insert/worker.rb#L135). But you could roll your own conflict resolution strategy; [docs here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT).